# Create dictionary from csv using pandas with date as key

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas

I wish to create dictionary from the table below

```
ID    ArCityArCountry         DptCityDptCountry      DateDpt    DateAr
1922  ParisFrance             NewYorkUnitedState     2008-03-10 2001-02-02
1002  LosAngelesUnitedState   California UnitedState 2008-03-10 2008-12-01
1901  ParisFrance             LagosNigeria           2001-03-05 2001-02-02
1922  ParisFrance             NewYorkUnitedState     2011-02-03 2008-12-01
1002  ParisFrance             CaliforniaUnitedState  2003-03-04 2002-03-04
1099  ParisFrance             BeijingChina           2011-02-03 2009-02-04
1901  LosAngelesUnitedState   ParisFrance            2001-03-05 2001-02-02
```

.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import csv
#import numpy as np

out= open("testfile.csv", "rb")
data = csv.reader(out)
data = [[row[0],row[1] + row[2],row[3] + row[4], row[5],row[6]] for row in data]
out.close()
print data

out=open("data.csv", "wb")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in data:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
for DateDpt, DateAr in df.iteritems():
    df.DateDpt = pd.to_datetime(df.DateDpt, format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df.DateAr = pd.to_datetime(df.DateAr, format='%Y-%m-%d')
print df
dept_cities = df.groupby('ArCityArCountry')

for city, departures in dept_cities:
    print(city)
    print([list(r) for r in departures.loc[:, ['AuthorID', 'DptCityDptCountry', 'DateDpt', 'DateAr']].to_records()])
```

Expected output
`ParisFrance = { DateAr, ID, ArCityArCountry, DptCityDptCountry}`
Note: I want to group by ArCityArCountry and DptCityDptCountry

You will notice I didn't include DateDpt; I want to select all IDs that fall between DateAr and DateDpt and actually in ParisFrance or CaliforniaUnitedStates between the specified periods.

for example In 1999-10-02 Mr A was in Paris until 2013-12-12 and Mr B was in Paris in 2010-11-04 and left 2012-09-09 that means MrA and Mr B were in Paris since MrB's visit to Paris fall in btw the time

MrA was there `CaliforniaUnitedStates =  { DateAr, ID, ArCityArCountry, DptCityDptCountry}`

Comment: Do you want a list DateAr's in the ParisFrance's dictionary?

Comment: *Expected output ParisFrance = { DateAr, ID, ArCityArCountry, DptCityDptCountry}*  This creates a tuple not a dictionary. Can show actual result data according to your example input.

Comment: Clayton Wahlstrom; yes exactly as you said

Comment: Mike Muller; all I want is dictionary of each value under ArCityArCountry with DateAr being the indices. I might have presented a poor output though

Comment: I get this error: "df.DateDpt = pd.to_datetime(df.DateDpt, format='%Y-%m-%d')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DateDpt'"